# Drawing Paths Between Circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have 5 different circle contained within separate `g` elements in my D3.js application - they are laid out horizontally (all with the same `y` position)

```
var vis = d3.select("body).append("svg:svg")

var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
       .data(nodes);

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i){
         return "translate(" + (i * 200) + ",0)";
      });

nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("fill", "green")
      .style("stroke", "green")
      })
```

I want to draw a path between all circles starting from the first node to the last, here's what I have so far

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
     .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
     .interpolate("linear");

vis.selectAll(".link")
     .data(nodes.children)
     .enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", "link")
     .attr("d", lineFunction(nodes));
```

However my lineFunction() fails as the nodes have no x or y attributes. Do I need to define these manually or am I over-complicating this?

Note the number of objects will grow and I'll need to draw paths between them regardless of the number.

Comment: Circles have `cx` and `cy` attributes (centerX and centerY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case described by you

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i){
         return "translate(" + (i * 200) + ",0)";//circles are placed using the translate in the g
      });
```

The circles don't have cx and cy they are put in their position using the translate of the g which contains it.

So for drawing the line you will need to provide the same x function in the line function, not

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
     .x(function(d) { return d.x; }) //this is wrong
     .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
     .interpolate("linear");
```

Should be more like this

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
     .x(function(d) { return (i * 200) ; }) //as in translate x of circle
     .y(function(d) { return 0; })//as in translate y of circle
     .interpolate("linear");
```

I have made a small working snippet [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8nmqot5h/).

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked fine (though I think you need to include the `i` index as you did in your fiddle. When learning a new framework it's really easy for me to forget the simple details. Thanks again

Comment: I know SVG has no concept of z-index or layering, but would you also know how to keep the path behind circle nodes?

Comment: To do that you will need to draw the path first and then the circles. something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8nmqot5h/1/